# Connecting to Cassandra Data using Sparklyr

Tags: r, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio. Installed a local version of Spark, run a few things, quite happy. Now I am trying to read my actual data from a Cluster, using RStudio Server and a standalone version of Spark. Data is in Cassandra, and I do not know how to connect to it. Can anyone point me to a good primer on how to connect and read that data?

Answer (score 1):

there is a package called `crassy` and is listed on the official sparklyr site's under Extensions.  You can search for crassy in GitHub.

Comment: A link to crassy would be useful